# jquery show/hide form field based on a variable number value

Tags: jquery, html-select, hide

I'm new to jquery and attempting to show/hide an Option Field in a Select Input based upon a number value ( from a DB query) comparison. When the number from the DB query reaches 50 I need to hide the Select Option. Googled and searched and find many variations of show/hide but am unable to come up with a working solution. This is my latest approuch and it too, doesn't work. Any suggestions or possible directions to explore would be most appreciated.

The jQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var myCount = '50';   //will be pulled from a DB query

    $("#date-time2-1").attr("temp", 'myCount');

    if ($("#date-time2-1").val($(this).attr("temp")) > '49') {
    $("#date-time2-1").hide();
    } else {
    $("#date-time2-1").show();

    }

    );
```

The Form html:

```
<h2>Example Registration Form</h2>

    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
      <table width="600" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td><label for="exfname">First Name</label>
          <input class="validate[required]" type="text" name="exfname" id="exfname" />
          <label for="exlname">Last Name</label>
          <input class="validate[required]" type="text" name="exlname" id="exlname" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
          <label for="datetime">Date-Session</label>
          <select class="validate[required]" name="datetime" size="1" id="datetime">
          <option value="" selected="selected">Please Select Date/Time</option>
          <option  id="date-time2-1"  value="" >Sept 3,2013 - 8:00AM</option>
          <option id="date-time1-2"  value="">Oct. 5, 2013 - 9:00AM</option>
          <option id="date-time1-1"  value="">Nov. 23, 2013 - 10:00AM</option>
          </select>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><p>
            <input  type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
            &nbsp;
            <input type="reset" name="Reset" id="Reset" value="Clear Form" />
          </p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
```

thank you.

Bob P.

Comment: Why do u use strings `49`, `50` instead numbers 49, 50?

Answer (score 0):

yo have to "unquote"

```
$("#date-time2-1").attr("temp", 'myCount');
```

to

```
$("#date-time2-1").attr("temp", myCount);
```

bacause you want to pass a variable not a string

and better parse the db query as Int like

```
var myCount = parseInt(numberfromDB);
```

then you can handle it like a real integer and also unquote

```
> '49'
```

to

```
> 49
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things wrong with the code, I'll go through them:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var myCount = '50';   //will be pulled from a DB query

    //Right here, myCount shouldn't be quoted, or else your setting the attribute temp to "myCount"
    //$("#date-time2-1").attr("temp", 'myCount');
    $("#date-time2-1").attr("temp", myCount);

    //What is "this" referring to, the DOM ready statement? Simply compare the value like this: 
    //if ($("#date-time2-1").val($(this).attr("temp")) > 49) { //unquoted your number as well, since you're comparing numbers not strings

    //Or if you want to compare the temp value, use .attr("temp")
    if ($("#date-time2-1").val() > '49') {
        $("#date-time2-1").hide();
    } else {
        $("#date-time2-1").show();
    }
);
```

Comment: To All who responded. Thank you. I've removed the Quotes from the value 50 and 49 and myCount, but still not working.

Comment: Removed the Use of $this... changed that line to:  if ($("#date-time2-1").attr("temp") > 49) { ..... but doesn't work.

Comment: Aaaand? What happened @user2640112

Comment: What I have now is this but it doesn't work.......:$(document).ready(function () {
    var myCount = 50;   //will be pulled from a DB query

    $("#date-time2-1").attr("temp", myCount);

    if ($("#date-time2-1").attr("temp") > 49) {
    $("#date-time2-1").hide();
    } else {
    $("#date-time2-1").show();

    }

});

Comment: @user2640112 -- What's your console say

Comment: Put a `console.log('test');` inside your `if` statement, does it ever get run?

Comment: I did get a Console Error when running the script (not cosole.log)     Timestamp: 8/1/2013 11:48:18 AM
Error: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMWindow.content]

Comment: Thank you for the help, I'll research it further

Comment: @user2640112 -- Seems to be firefox related, is that your browser when testing?

Answer (score 0):

You are using numbers not strings

And myCount it is a variable in the attr

```
var myCount = 50;//get ride of the '

$("#date-time2-1").attr("temp", myCount);//get ride of the "

if ($("#date-time2-1").val($(this).attr("temp")) > 49) {//get ride of the '
```

Answer (score 0):

Well lets start by making your code sexy:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var myCount = '50';   //carefull with the quotes, if your not sure about the input you can always use intval()

$("#date-time2-1").attr("temp", myCount); // myCount has no quotes or else it wont work, because you dont want a string here
  if ($("#date-time2-1").val($(this).attr("temp")) > '49') { //Again same as above not a fan of the quotes
      $("#date-time2-1").hide();
  } else {
     $("#date-time2-1").show();
  }
}); //Close the document.ready
```